# How SVC mode is changed to USER mode?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, system-calls

I understand in latest ARM architecture by 'SVC 0' (system call)instruction USER mode is switched to SVC mode.
And return value of system call is stored in r0 register, SPSR_SVC is copied to CPSR .
I want to know how which api does this ?

Comment: You are doing a very poor job of asking questions.  I think you really want to know how the Linux kernel is handling this.  As I read your question *literally*, Notlikethat has described exactly what you want.  There is an API of sorts for the Linux kernel, but besides the *wrong* tags, you made no mention about this.  In this case, [svc_entry](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.S) might be interesting.  This is not meant to be an insult only some advice to help you to get the answer you might want faster and provide useful Q/A.

Answer (score 1):

The *architectural operation* of the `SVC` instruction is to save the CPSR into SPSR_SVC, save the address of the following instruction to LR_SVC, switch the CPU into SVC mode, set the PC to the SVC exception vector (0x08) and continue exectuting from there. That's just what the hardware *does* for that instruction (as a single atomic operation) - there is no "API" involved. The SVC handler code, once it's done whatever it wants to, will usually execute one of the exception return instructions<sup>*</sup>, which will essentially do all that in reverse - restore the mode and CPSR state from SPSR_SVC, set the PC to LR_SVC, and continue in the restored mode.

Now, [any other ABI on top of that](http://www.arm.linux.org.uk/developer/patches/viewpatch.php?id=3105/4) is entirely the choice of whatever system is being implemented. If Linux [chooses to use r0 to return a value](http://www.arm.linux.org.uk/developer/patches/viewpatch.php?id=3105/4), then that's just how its syscall handler code is written. Other systems might do something entirely different.

---

<sup>*</sup>depending on instruction set, the level the exception was taken at, and whether the stack is involved or not, usually one of [`ERET`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473k/dom1361289871515.html), [`SUBS PC, LR, #0`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473k/dom1361289908769.html), or [`LDM` with PC in the list and the `^` suffix](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473k/dom1361289873045.html).

Comment: " SVC handler code, once it's done whatever it wants to,will usually execute one of the exception return instructions"
 - What are these instructions I want to know.